# How do I get an element within a table cell?

Tags: javascript

The number which you put down inside the **input** field, defines a cell in the table. 
What I want is to "reach" a **cell div**'s first **span**  within the same **if** statement (which defines the red color for the chosen cell).
If it's not possible to get it inside the existing **if** statement, how else can I get it?
Please, help.

Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/th6vujjp/1/

or below:

```js
var number = document.getElementById('number');

    number.onchange = function() {
    
    var v = this.value;
    
    var tdAttr = document.querySelector('td[data-cell|="'+v+'"]');
    
     
    
    if(tdAttr) {  tdAttr.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

    }
 

}
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

 
td[data-cell|=""] {
    background-color: red;
}

 
input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
```

```html
<form>
  <input data-type="number" placeholder="Day" id="number" maxlength="2"  >
</form>



<table>

    <tr>

        <td data-cell="1-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="2-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="3-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="4-01-15"></td>

    </tr>

        <tr>

        <td data-cell="5-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="6-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="7-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="8-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

        <tr>

        <td data-cell="9-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="10-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="11-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="12-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

        <tr>

        <td data-cell="13-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="14-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="15-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td data-cell="16-01-15">
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What should I write within my statement: 
  if(tdAttr) {  tdAttr.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

    }
to retrieve the 1st span of the chosen cell?
The chosen cell is defined by the number we put inside the input field. E.g. I put number 4, the 4th cell inside the table turns to red - it is my chosen cell and I want to retrieve its 1st span inside my IF statement I gave above.

Comment: `document.querySelector('td[data-cell|="'+v+'"] span:nth-child(1)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var number = document.getElementById('number');

    number.onchange = function() {

    var v = this.value;

    var tdAttr = document.querySelector('td[data-cell|="'+v+'"]');
    if(tdAttr) { 
               tdAttr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
               tdAttr.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML ="Tamem";
    }
}
```